# Queue manager for a laptop?

Tags: kde, job-control

Is there a lightweight queue manager for Kubuntu? Something like torque, but as I understand it - torque works for clusters only - while I want the similar thing for my laptop.

The problem is - I'd like to start a job only if the previous jobs have finished. So I need a program which will queue the jobs, and run the next one once the previous have finished.

Comment: What kind of jobs you want to run? Torque is a system to run hpc tasks so it is used in clusters, but i think you can configure it in  a single machine. Instead of having a server and N "worker" machines, your laptop will be the server and a worker.

Comment: Yeah - I tried to find some guides how to set up torque to use in a single laptop - but found none.

Comment: Can you explain what kinds of "jobs" you want to run?

Comment: @Adobe There's an article at [Ubuntu Wiki](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1512061) explaining how to setup Torque in a single machine. It's for ubuntu 10.04 but should work in more recent versions.

Comment: @izx: numerically intensive jobs (simple molecular dynamics simulations).

Comment: Thanks. Is each job a command-line invocation, or is there a GUI involved somewhere?

Comment: @izx: Oh - that's what You meant. It's a CLI alright.

Answer (score 3):

You could use Redis, which is lightweight and simple. I would refer you to [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7241310/818667), which contains a few good links.